# iOS6 crash <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5, ipad-3

I'm stucked over one week I cant figure it out why my app crashed only in IPAD3 ios6.0.1, all other ipads does not crash, my app uses a lot of memory because it downloads a lot of contents and uses also a lot of webviews,

here is the crash log:

```
iPad-3 backboardd[51] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 23: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
iPad-3 backboardd[51] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 23: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
iPad-3 UserEventAgent[13] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
iPad-3 com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.mmm.ipad[0x1066][1275]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.mmm.ipad[0x1066]) Exited: Killed: 9
iPad-3 com.apple.debugserver-189[1274] <Warning>: 1 +0.000000 sec [04fa/1303]: error: ::read ( 5, 0x1b5a0c, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
backboardd[51] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 23: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
iPad-3 backboardd[51] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.mmm.ipad[0x1066]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
<Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
<Notice>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2013-01-17-114238.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
```

Comment: Having the same exact problems. I use a lot of UIWebViews as well, and get the same type of error, thought I'm releasing my UIWebViews using the following code https://gist.github.com/4628265, which should avoid all memory leaks. Are you by chance downloading video media?

Comment: I have figure it out, its connecting memory leaks , check the instruments for seeking the problem

Comment: That's the problem - Instruments said I have zero leaks and my app's allocatiosn are steady. The mediaserverd daemon's allocations are crazy - it keeps growing and growing until the app crashes. It has something to do with AVPlayer...

Comment: yes its not leak issues, it means that uses a lot of memory more than the device has so in the new versions of ios mainly it will crash automatically when ios detect that your app is using a lot of memory