# Application Crashing on iOS 6 Device

Tags: ios, ios6, crash-reports

My application is running fine on iOS7 and iOS6 simulator, but is ceasing on iPhone 3GS running iOS6. We are getting following error.

*libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary*

Kindly help me and let me know what is the cause of this error

thanks

Comment: Duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376347/ios6-crash-error-libmobilegestalt-copysystemversiondictionaryvalue ?

Comment: Memory leaks. 3GS is a very very slow device. Most of my app that work fine on iphone 4 and up are a hit and miss on 3GS.